# Get first element of list as Maybe vs Maybe elements

Tags: functional-programming

In Haskell or fp languages we have maybe monad (Option, Some, None). The names could vary.

So lets say I have function returning first element of list or None if empty.

```
headm [] = None()
headm (x:xs) = Some(x)
```

So now I have function which gets all values from map and keys as maybe:

```
keyValues ['name','age'] {age:24} // [None, Some(24)]
```

I know maps are not syntax correct but the code is just for demonstration purpose.

So if I call headm on empty list I get None.

If I call headm of the result above I also get None.

My question is inst this confusing because i get the same result for empty list and if head of the list has none.

Is it good practice and I should check if the list is empty?

Comment: thanks, i edited the title hope it is better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, the premise of your question actually isn't quite right because you would *not* get `None` when applying `headm` to the `[None, Some(24)]` list you have described. You would instead get `Some(None)`.

To use a Haskell example to make things more concrete, we can define `headm` as<sup>1</sup>:

```
headm :: [a] -> Maybe a
headm []     = Nothing
headm (x:xs) = Just x
```

If we apply this to the empty list, we do indeed get `Nothing`:

```
ghci> headm []
Nothing
```

*However*, if we apply this to the list `[Nothing, Just 24]`:

```
ghci> headm [Nothing, Just 24]
Just Nothing
```

These are two distinct values (which is why they are printed differently) which are not equal to each other. The values `Just (Just Nothing)`, `Just (Just (Just Nothing))`, etc, also exist and are distinct from each other (they all in fact potentially have different types, depending on how/if their types are constrained).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note: `headm` already exists in the Haskell standard library. It is called `listToMaybe` and it exists in `Data.Maybe`.

Comment: Thanks, i was wrong. Indeed it returns Some(None). But I wonder is there some cases where both returns the same type. And why the function headm is called listToMaybe since it only returns the first element.

Comment: @user2693928 Such a case is completely impossible, because the empty list case is, by definition, the only case that gives you `None`. Non-empty lists will *always* give you `Some ...` . `listToMaybe` is called that because it turns a list into a `Maybe` and there is another function called `maybeToList` which goes the other direction.